# Installed laptop-mode-tool 16.04, now USB mouse not working after rebooting until it is re plughed in

Tags: usb, mouse, suspend, laptop, 16.04

I did a fresh install of 16.04 on my vizio ct14-a0 ultrabook.

I installed `laptop-mode-tools`

Then I edited the `AUTOSUSPEND_TIMEOUT` in `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf` file from `2` to `0`:

```
# Auto-Suspend timeout in seconds
# Number of seconds after which the USB devices should suspend
AUTOSUSPEND_TIMEOUT=2
```

This worked like a charm for me on 15.10, now  the mouse isn't detected after a fresh boot until it is unplugged and plugged back in.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and you have to do a couple of steps:

1. In terminal check with `lsusb`, the ID vendor and ID product of your mouse. In my case I have a wheel optical mouse from Microsoft. So id is 045e:0040

   ```
   $ lsusb
   Bus 002 Device 004: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
   ```
2. Next edit your `/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf` using `sudo` and check if the line is set to

   ```
   AUTOSUSPEND_USE_WHITELIST=0
   ```
3. Next, add the result of `lsusb` ID of your mouse as follows:

   ```
   AUTOSUSPEND_RUNTIME_DEVID_BLACKLIST="045e:0040"
   ```
4. Reboot and everything should be ok with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I've not figured out yet how to fix this issue permanently, but there is **workaround** that worked to me.

First off, you should discover which is your device:

```
# lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 056d:c087 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
```

Pay attention to the *bus number* and *id*. Then, go to `/sys/bus/usb/devices` and you will see that folder contains a lot of symlinks. Using `Bus 003` as reference, you should dig into `3-*` folders.

```
# ll
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 3-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-0:1.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 3-1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 3-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 4-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/usb4/4-0:1.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 5-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-0:1.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 6-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb6/6-0:1.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 7-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-0:1.0/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 usb1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 usb2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 nov 17 20:33 usb3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/
...
```

You'll notice every single folder has two files `idVendor` and `idProduct`. These files contain those *id* you got previously, through `lsusb` command. That was the tricky part.

Once you have identified the device (rename `usb3/3-1` folders accordingly), run:

```
echo 'on' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/3-1/power/control
```

The only inconvenient is that this solution is **not permanent**, and you should run it again every time you reboot your laptop (use *reverse-i-search* `Ctrl+R` then, will make all easier)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by modifying:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf
```

At the last line

```
AUTOSUSPEND_TIMEOUT=2
```

replace `2` with `99999999`

```
AUTOSUSPEND_TIMEOUT=99999
```

save and reboot.